# Windows Server 2012 issues configuring 8TB raid array

Tags: raid, windows-server-2012

I've just restored an image of our default server config on a DELL R710 with a H700 raid controller. The controller has a single raid 5 array of 5*2TB disk + 1 Hotspare.

Windows boots just fine, but I have some issues correctly setting up the drive partions.

The Disk Managment shows the (almost) 8TB drive, it has the normal OS partitions, and 2 parts of unallocated space.

I would like to create one big partition of all the unallocated space, but I can not seem to do so. I can not remove either of the unallocated blocks to create one new big unallocated block.

I can not convert to dynamic or GPT disk because those options are greyed out.

Please help...

image:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30546398/diskmanagement.png

Comment: Don't use RAID 5, especially with large disks.  Unless, of course, you're *trying* to lose all your data, then carry on.

Answer (score 1):

As HN says you REALLY don't want to be using R5 for large disks, in the event of having to replace one or more disks during the life of the server you're guaranteeing at least one unrecoverable error - use R6 or R10 ok.

Anyway basically it can't be one bit disk 0, I don't know the H700 but if you can carve up an array in the same way as the HP controllers I know then what you do is create your R6 or R10 array then create a logical disk 1 of whatever size you want for your OS disk 0/C: drive then present the rest as logical disk 2 to be your OS disk 1/D: drive and partition it using GPT - you'll be fine then.

Comment: Fair enough.. been doing some reading and it would seem that RAID 5 for large arrays has some real downsides.

What your you do?
1) RAID 6 array of 6 disks, no hotspare. Array size: 8TB
2) RAID 6 array of 5 disks + hot spare. Array size: 6TB
3) RAID 10 array of 6 disks + no hotspare. Array size: 6TB

Comment: I love R10 myself and use it for almost everything.

Comment: So, I changed my array to Raid 10, re-imaged the system, but have the same issue.
I can not see an option on the H700 to create on R10 array and split that in 2 logical drives... So either I'm missing something there or I should be looking for another way...

Comment: You will, I mustn't have been clear enough I guess, you're going to struggle to make this work if you keep presenting it all as one big disk 0 - I don't know Dell kit but look into whether you can carve up the array in the controller more please. Other than that you may have to stick in a R1 pair of smaller OS disks or switch out the controller for a more functional one.